# Accuracy of the Miller-Rabin test?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

The Miller-Rabin primality test relies on a condition $W_n(b) \implies n$ is composite, and [this paper](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0022314X80900840/1-s2.0-0022314X80900840-main.pdf?_tid=04d1b9f8-c5b5-11e6-9fd9-00000aacb35f&acdnat=1482129374_ecf773985fcd9bdb8b8a9a8b50f6d570) gives a somewhat hefty proof of why the algorithm bears at most $\frac{1}{4}$ false witnesses $b$ to the primality of $n$, i.e. that $\frac{|\{b | W_n(b)\}|}{(n-1)} \geqslant \frac{3}{4}$. Does anyone know of perhaps a simpler proof or some background from which I can more accessibly approach the proof?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An elementary analysis of this happens on page 3 of [Jerry Shurman's notes](http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/361/lectures/bigprimes.pdf)